# Does maven care about file names?

Tags: maven, jar

I am trying to install some dependencies using maven in a spring boot project.
I am looking for a jar

> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:3.1.0

But I wanna know if the jar file should have this name `maven-resources-plugin`, or if the file name is not important for maven. I mean if maven will automatically know which jar file should use.

I will appreciate any help or feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a plugin, not a dependency as such (meaning that Maven needs it for building your project, your code doesn't need it to compile or run).

You should only have to specify the plugins groupId, artifactId and version plus any configuration in your pom.xml, and Maven knows exactly what jar to get and how to use it.

See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/plugin-info.html for further information.

Comment: Note that Spring Boot in general does a very good job of using properties to define dependency version numbers.   Always have a look at the effective pom to see if the plugin/dependency is already included and if so just override the property value in your own pom.